# Exporting Bezier curves from R?

Tags: r, plot, vector-graphics, bezier, smoothing

Plotting a sine curve with R and saving the output as PDF:

```
curve(sin, -2*pi, 2*pi, xname = "t")
dev.copy2pdf(file='sine.pdf')
```

yields a curve that looks pretty smooth at first glance:

[image]

However, when zooming in to the PDF, you can see that the curve really consists of a sequence of linear segments:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Is there any way to export truly smooth line graphics from R as Bezier curves?

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Take a look at [10 tips for making your R graphics look their best](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/01/10-tips-for-making-your-r-graphics-look-their-best.html)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to export truly smooth line graphics from R as Bezier curves?

No. However, you can increase the number of segments used to draw the curve, which will have much the same effect:

```
curve(sin, -2*pi, 2*pi, xname = "t", n=1001)
dev.copy2pdf(file='sine.pdf')
```

[image]

(1200% resolution)

Comment: This seems like a very wasteful solution that leads to needlessly bloated output files.

Comment: The pdf in question is 10k in size, which is tiny by modern standards. There certainly _are_ situations in R that lead to bloated graphics (hint: think scatterplots) but this isn't one of them.

Comment: Yes but what if you have hundreds of line objects (e.g., error ellipses)? This could easily create megabyte sized images. With Bezier curves, that would reduce to kilobytes.

Comment: Megabyte-sized images are nothing nowadays. Now if you have 10- or 100-MB sized images, that's a problem.

Comment: If you have that many ellipses, you can also export to a bitmap rather than a vector format which effectively puts a cap on how big your file size can get.

Comment: and remember that there is no "bloat" if you generate images such that they look smooth unless zoomed in. That's simply the size things are when you need high enough resolution. Bloat is when you waste bytes on things that no one will ever see: play around with the step increment to find the sweet spot between "readers can see polygons" vs "readers see smooth lines" at whatever zoom you can reasonably expect them to use.